# How to remove an Element present inside nested div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="myordersdiv" style="display: block;">
   <ul>
      <li class="myorderhead active">
         <h5>
            My Orders
            <i class="myorderhead22">2</i>
         </h5>
      </li>
      <div id="ordersdiv">
         <div id="addtoordersdiv53">
         </div>
         <div id="addtoordersdiv54">
         </div>
         </div>
   </ul>
   <div class="confirmorder-row">
      <a id="ordersconfirm" hrer="#" class="btn btn-confirmorder">confirm order</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The above is the HTML content of my website

On Uncheck of a  Checkbox , i need to remove **addtoordersdiv54**

Inside a checkbox  Listener ,  i have this code

```
var id_attr_val = 54 ;
   $("#myordersdiv addtoordersdiv"+id_attr_val).remove;
```

But its not removing that element , could anybody please help .

Comment: Another problem with the code is you forgot the `()` after `remove`, and it's a method, not a property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID's are unique, doesn't matter if it's nested, just target the unique indentifier.

```
var id_attr_val = 54 ;
$("#addtoordersdiv" + id_attr_val).remove();
```

The issue with your code is missing the hash in front of the second ID, and not executing the remove function

```
$("#myordersdiv #addtoordersdiv" + id_attr_val).remove();
```

But again, targeting elements with two ID's make no sense, as an ID is **unique** !